# How can I send init data to a Mithril component

Tags: mithril.js

I'm trying to initialize a Mithril component by setting the ID to fetch data from the server as follows:

```
// view/UserList.js
module.exports = {
    oninit: function(vnode) {
        console.log(vnode);
        var groupId = vnode.attrs.groupId;
        console.log('The group ID is '+groupId);
        User.loadUsersInGroup(groupId);
    },
    view: ...
}
```

I have the following:

```
var userList = require('./view/UserList');
m.mount(document.body, UserList, {groupId: 5});
```

But I get:

```
vnode.attrs is undefined
```

---

I tried to change it to:

```
var UserList = require('./view/UserList');
m.mount(document.body, m(UserList, {groupId: 5}));
```

But now I get:

```
m.mount(element, component) expects a component, not a vnode
```

How can I get the vnode.attrs to be populated correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to send initialization data to a component can be found at https://mithril.js.org/mount.html#description.

> To pass arguments when mounting a component use:
>
> ```
> m.mount(element, {view: function () {return m(Component, attrs)}})
> ```

So applied to this case, it would be:

```
m.mount(document.body, {view: function() { return m(UserList, {groupId: 5}); }});
```

Some other ways to do it are:

```
const full   = {view: vnode => m('h1', vnode.attrs.test)}
const short  = {view: v => m('h1', v.attrs.test)}
const dest   = {view: ({attrs}) => m('h1', attrs.test)}
const destf  = {view: ({attrs: {test}}) => m('h1', test)}

m.mount(document.body, {
  view: () => [
    m(full,  {test: "full"}),
    m(short, {test: "short"}),
    m(dest,  {test: "destructured"}),
    m(destf, {test: "fully destructured"})
  ]
})
```

[See them in action here.](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgZglgNgpgziAXAbVAOwIYFsZJAOgAsAXLKEAGhAGMB7NYmBvEAXwvW10QICsEqdBk2J4hcYgAIwAVyhRJigLyTgANwgwA7oklq0tACYxJSgHySsACgDkhAIw2Keg8fwZixAE5x8jCQCUrAA6aOJScIS0XlKmqhraumqmFtZ2js5q7p4+fvDEQaHhksYSinHqmjqSVsAe3nCsASmWtg5OkvW5-gUhYfRlpcRgyvFVurVdcLrAPaxNLWntzj2FaKFY+Fi0MgxWhrTUMjgM+ABGRgCezsChignVVs3mksh35day8s6qPbrB4DkUABTQo70U1ki0WINz+kgBUJiIICYLQ5VaQx+s3y-xAQy8MmoxBkXhghmRqPR1iGYFhOPhgPklxK+QJRJJZOR7wAuqEmmwOCBMDg8PhqHABDR6IxmDw2NyqFAIGgANYIFCcEU8LAQYiELzQSggEnkHgkYgAB2mAHprbsLSqAOZi2hYa06vUGqAAAXs+D9AFZ3br9dB8PwjcRLhbuCAI+xNbGPaGoABaCSk7BGk14c1WxC2+1Ol1u5Ne9PeGDYX3+-AABmtGarmwjVCjMbw8e5rCAA) (courtesy of osban on the Mithril.js Gitter chat)